# Grep/sed/awk or pull certain information in a file using regex/linux commands

Tags: linux, sed, grep, syslog

I have file with this output, and I am trying to collect useful data from my file.

```
R1#show ip route 192.168.5.130
Routing Descriptor Blocks:

  * 192.168.5.128, from 192.168.5.162, 00:20:16 ago, via Serial0/0/0.2

      Route metric is 2172416, traffic share count is 1

      Total delay is 20100 microseconds, minimum bandwidth is 1544 Kbit/sec

      Reliability 255/255, minimum MTU 1500 bytes

      Loading 1/255, Hops 1
```

I want to grep match if my above paragraph have word "metric" then it should display the whole paragraph not just that line.

Also is there a way I can check condition that if metric==2172416 then return the whole paragraph.

I would like to know the simplest and easiest way to do it, since I am going to apply that in different scenarios.

Also If I have this in my file, how can fetch just the lines from Apr 11? Can I use wildcard here?

```
CPU0:Apr 11 05:22:04.768 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-INTCHG : 

CPU0:Apr 11 05:22:04.769 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-NBRCHG : 

CPU0:Apr 11 05:22:04.769 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-NBRCHG : 

CPU0:Apr 11 06:09:53.066 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-INTCHG : 

CPU0:Apr 11 06:09:53.066 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-NBRCHG : 

CPU0:Apr 11 06:09:56.707 UTC: pim[1182]: %ROUTING-IPV4_PIM-5-NBRCHG :
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/Route metric is 2172416/,/Loading/' file.txt
```

above command prints the line starts from **Route metric is 2172416** and ends with **Loading** line

```
awk '/Apr 11/' second_file.txt
grep 'Apr 11' second_file.txt
```

above command will print the lines having **Apr 11**. you can use grep as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data in the first file is exactly as you have shown it, with blank lines, you may use GNU `grep` (or a few others) and ask for surrounding context:

```
grep -B 5 -A 6 -F 'Route metric is 2172416' file
```

This will return 5 lines of context before the match, and 6 lines of context after the match, along with the line containing the fixed string `Route metric is 2172416`.

To get all lines mentioning `Apr 11`:

```
grep -F 'Apr 11' file
```

or, if you need a more specific matching criteria

```
grep '^CPU0:Apr 11' file
```

... which requires that the given pattern matches at the start of the line.